# I am new to python scripting.Please how can i filter and export the line to a new text file

Tags: python

Please how can i write python code to extract only phone number from text file. Then save in extract in another text file.

Textfile sample:

```
"Name": Farouk, "Age": 23, "Address": No. 582, Chile crescent, Kenya, "Phone number": 231765987
"Name": Ben, "Age": 23, "Address": No. 582, Chile crescent, Kenya, "Phone number": 21690860
```

Comment: please make an attempt first, then if you run into a problem provide a [mcve]

Comment: First problem: How do you even *detect* a phone number?

Comment: Seeing as  `"Phone number": 231765987 "Name": Ben,` itself presents parsing issues, this would be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is actually a newline "\n" between `, "Phone number": 231765987 "Name": Ben,`

Like:

```
"Name": Farouk, "Age": 23, "Address": No. 582, Chile crescent, Kenya, "Phone number": 231765987 
"Name": Ben, "Age": 23, "Address": No. 582, Chile crescent, Kenya, "Phone number": 21690860
```

This would do the trick:

```
with open("./data.txt") as read_file: # The file being read
    with open("./Phone Numbers.txt", 'w') as write_file: # New file being created
        for data in read_file:
            for d in data.strip("\n").split(','):
                if "Phone number" in d:
                    write_file.write(d[16:].strip(" ") + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

as a initial suggestion, you should write some code before asking some help. If you share some code, others will directly start working on your problem.

To solve this problem, 
   first you need to read the file line by line.
   If each line contains text you pasted in problem, you can use regex to search for phone number.
   You can also convert this string to JSON, but there is not valid format as address don't have quotes. so better to use regex to solve this.

Find example code to solve this

```
import re
content = []
file_name = 'sample'
with open(file_name) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

for line in content:
    m = re.search("\"Phone number\": (\w+)", line)
    if m is None:
        print("There is no success for search.")
    else:
        print(m.groups()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import errno
import csv
import re
i = 0
path = 'C:/Users/Mallam Farouk Sanusi/Desktop/k/*.txt'
files = glob.glob(path)
for name in files:
try:
    with open(name) as f:
        csv.field_size_limit(1310720)
        s = csv.reader(f)
        for line in s:
            print (line[9])

        i = i+1
```

Comment: Here is the text file i am searching
{"HHNo":"NW/KD/BIR/13/1/013","Zone":"NORTH-WEST","State":"KADUNA","LGA":"BIRNIN GWARI","Ward":"MAGAJIN GARI II","Community":"13","HHAddress":"GELOBAI ROAD,  NEAR","HHHName":"GAMBO MALAM MAISHAYI","NSRRefNo":"NW/KD/BIR/13/1/013/02","BeneficiaryName":"AISHATU MALAM GAMBO MAISHAYI","BeneficiaryAge":"45","BeneficiaryPhone":null,"Role":"Caregiver"

Comment: I tried making the code above, but it only prints value of index 9. I want it to print the value of a pattern (BeneficiaryName). how can i adjust my code to print the value of the pattern (BeneficiaryName)